# МетАтеза, но метОнимия?

Tags: орфография

Поймал себя на мысли, что интуитивно хочется привести написание слов мет**а**теза (или мет**а**фора) и мет**о**нимия к единообразию.

Или найти объяснение различиям в существующем написании.

Comment: Это различие существовало уже в греческом языке, так что к русскому отношения не имеет.

Comment: Вопрос быдл бы интересным, будь побольше примеров на "метонимия".

Answer (score 1):

> Или найти объяснение различиям в существующем написании.

По-моему, при образовании слова *метонимия* была просто-напросто усечена приставка *meta…* (как и при образовании  слова *метод*: гр. ***met***a… + **od**os "путь, способ" -> лат. ***met***hodus -> нем. ***Met***hode) -- чтобы не было стечения двух гласных.

гр. *meta… + **thesis*** "положение" -> *metathesis* "перестановка" -> *мета**теза***

гр. *meta… + **phoros*** "несущий" -> *metaphora* "перенос" -> *мета**фора***

гр. *meta… + **onyma*** "имя" -> **нем.** *Met**onymie*** -> *мет**онимия***

Comment: Греки усекали "приставку"? (др.-греч. μετονυμία — «переименование», от μετά — «над» и ὄνομα/ὄνυμα — «имя»)

Comment: Да, похоже на стяжение гласных.

Comment: Эти слова не могли быть заимствованы из древнегреческого, это новообразования, придуманные лингвистами относительно  недавней эпохи. Поэтому и ссылка на то, что "так в греческом" не проходит. Думаю, что slava1947 прав по сути. "Стяжение" произошло, когда эти слова конструировались лингвистами веке в девятнадцатом. А потом уже пошли гулять по миру в такой форме. Вот почему так поступили лингвисты - действительно не очень понятно, греческий к такой вольности не располагает, насколько понимаю. .

Answer (score 0):

Слова "метафора и метонимия" появились в русском языке **в качестве терминов риторики.** Они, как и другие слова с этим формантом,  восходят к греческому языку, затем  (часто **через латинский**) были заимствованы западноевропейскими и славянскими языками.

Эти термины использует еще **Ломоносов   в "Кратком руководстве к красноречию"**:
"Тропы речений знатнейшие суть шесть:  метафора, синекдоха, метонимия, антономазия, катахресис и металепсис".

**Метонимия** Заимств. в XVIII в. **из нем. яз**., где **Metonymie** < лат. metōnymia, передающего греч. metōnymia (meta «пере», onyma «имя», родственное имя, см.). Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004

**Метафора** Заимств. в XVIII в. **из франц. яз**., где **metaphora** — производное от metapherō «переношу».

Comment: Шанский - словарь для школьников. Не аргумент(с) вообще-то. Но как бы ьо тамги было это именно XVIII век, т.е. греческий *новодел*, искустьвенное образование. Поэтому отсулка к греческому "у них тоже так" не актуальна.

Comment: Материал первой части ответа взят из словаря Черных.  А почему это греческий новодел, если слова заимствованы через немецкий и французский языки? Надо же знать, когда они в эти языки пришли.

Comment: А что меняет, что через французский (я, кстати, сомневаюсь)? Тезис был такой, что таки писали на греческом. Кабы это были древние греки, это был бы аргумент самодостаточный. Но когда это реконструкция совсем недавнего времени, кто может сказать, что это правильно? А если правильно, то чем руководствовались изобретая такой вариант вопреки морфологии? Вот из латыни много слов заимствовано, транскрипция-транскрибировать, диффузия-диффундировать и т.п. Но это именно латынь, тут все объяснимо.

Comment: А метонимия - это по какой грамматике? "Паралимпиада" получается, нал который только ленивый не смеялся, если такую версию всерьез рассматривать..